# array of json with different values in scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, scalatest

```
"name": "Add Constant",
"taskType": "addConstants",
"id": 43,
"x": 100,
"y": 50,
"inputConnectors": [],
"outputConnectors": [{
"name": ""
}],
"argsMap":{"newColumnName" : "PI", "value" : 3.147}
```

I want to create array of 1000elements of above json but in every elements id will change increase by 1. can it possible in scala.How i will do ? I stuck bcz json object is string data how id will increment by 1?

```
for (a <- 1 to 1000) {
    var add_value = """"name": "Add Constant",
"taskType": "addConstants",
"id": 43+i,
"x": 100,
"y": 50,
"inputConnectors": [],
"outputConnectors": [{
"name": ""
}],
"argsMap":{"newColumnName" : "PI", "value" : 3.147}"""
  }
```

By this can we do?

Comment: you are pretty close, just do `43 + ${i}`. And do you want a list of JSON like `[{...}, {...}]`? or just `List[String]`?

Answer (score 0):

you should add an s at the beginning of the """ to use scala string interpolation and then use ${expression} to place the string

```
(1 to 1000).map(i => s""""name": "Add Constant",
"taskType": "addConstants",
"id": ${43+i},
"x": 100,
"y": 50,
"inputConnectors": [],
"outputConnectors": [{
"name": ""
}],
"argsMap":{"newColumnName" : "PI", "value" : 3.147}"""
)
```

PS Pi is  3.14159.. so 3.147 is too big :)